# VBA find left until space using FormulaR1C1

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a piece of VBA code that looks for the first two characters on the left which is:

```
Range("EB5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(Input!R[-2]C[-92],2)"
Range("EB5").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("EB5:EB" & rownumfinal)
```

I however want this to find the characters on the left until there is a space.

Could anyone advise on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of hard-coding `2` as the second argument for the `LEFT` function, use the `FIND` function:

```
"=LEFT(Input!R[-2]C[-92],FIND("" "",Input!R[-2]C[-92])-1)"
```

Also, [learn to avoid `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). It's often unnecessary, and a main cause of errors.

Your code can be simplified I think to a *single* statement:

```
Range("EB5:EB" & rownumfinal).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=LEFT(Input!R[-2]C[-92],FIND("" "",Input!R[-2]C[-92])-1)"
```

Comment: You need to double up the quotes within the formula. ;)

Comment: Also, I'd probably use `"=LEFT(Input!R[-2]C[-92]&"" "",FIND("" "",Input!R[-2]C[-92])-1)"` in case there isn't always a space in the original text. :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. This is causing a Compile error: Expected: end of statementafter the find(" 

Any thoughts?

Comment: @JDRows did you note the revision where we had to double the quotes?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain how do I make it so that if there is no space to return the value of the cell?

Comment: I am reasonably certain that if you play with your formula on a worksheet, you wlil be able to figure it out. You'll need to enclose your formula within an `IFERROR` formula...

Comment: SOmething like `=IFERROR(FIND(" ",Input!R[-2]C[-92]),Input!R[-2]C[-92], __the rest of your fomula__)`

Comment: @JDRows You could use what I put in my second comment.